Calls to Sonos API don't include credential information after being authenticated
I'm developing a "content service" for Sonos. I'm using OAuth as my Authentication Method in the Sonos sandbox.
I have implemented browser level authentication. The flow seems to work up to getMetadata but at this point no credentials/authentication tokens are sent, so I can't lookup the correct user to return the metadata.
getAppLink
The first call is to getAppLink:
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <credentials
            xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <deviceId>00-00-00-00-00-00:0</deviceId>
            <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
        </credentials>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <getAppLink
            xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <householdId>Sonos_SNBSD7YPBwpgYAw5W6b8Gf4TGS_211454cc</householdId>
            <hardware>Google:sunfish:Pixel 4a</hardware>
            <osVersion>13</osVersion>
            <sonosAppName>ACR_:Google:sunfish:Pixel 4a</sonosAppName>
            <callbackPath>sonos-2://x-callback-url/addAccount?state=iid%3Dcom.exam.sonos%26hhid%3DSonos_SNBSD7YPBwpgYAw5W6b8Gf4TGS.EKgI4Te8ewA7RL2sGRBD%26callbackPath%3D%2FaddAccount</callbackPath>
        </getAppLink>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

I reply:
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Body>
        <getAppLinkResponse
            xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <getAppLinkResult>
                <authorizeAccount>
                    <appUrlStringId>AppLinkMessage</appUrlStringId>
                    <deviceLink>
                        <regUrl>https://sonos.exam.com/login?linkCode=6f7b278b-097e-49a1-a393-879c0409b61b</regUrl>
                        <linkCode>6f7b278b-097e-49a1-a393-879c0409b61b</linkCode>
                        <showLinkCode>false</showLinkCode>
                    </deviceLink>
                </authorizeAccount>
            </getAppLinkResult>
        </getAppLinkResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

The HTTP log is:
"POST /ws/sonos HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Linux UPnP/1.0 Sonos/79.1-54060"

In the app this then redirects me to the regUrl and I log in successfully.
getDeviceAuthToken
getDeviceAuthToken is polled with:
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <credentials
            xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <deviceId>00-00-00-00-00-00:0</deviceId>
            <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
        </credentials>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <getDeviceAuthToken
            xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <householdId>Sonos_SNBSD7YPBwpgYAw5W6b8Gf4TGS_211454cc</householdId>
            <linkCode>6f7b278b-097e-49a1-a393-879c0409b61b</linkCode>
        </getDeviceAuthToken>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

We reply:
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Body>
        <getDeviceAuthTokenResponse
            xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <getDeviceAuthTokenResult>
                <authToken>mytoken</authToken>
                <privateKey>mykey</privateKey>
                <userInfo>
                    <nickname>nickname</nickname>
                    <userIdHashCode>hashcode</userIdHashCode>
                </userInfo>
            </getDeviceAuthTokenResult>
        </getDeviceAuthTokenResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

(I've shortened the responses above).
The HTTP log is:
"POST /ws/sonos HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Linux UPnP/1.0 Sonos/79.1-54060"

reportAccountAction
We then receive (note the token and key is included inside loginToken):
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <credentials
            xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <deviceId>00-00-00-00-00-00:0</deviceId>
            <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
            <loginToken>
                <token>mytoken</token>
                <key>mykey</key>
                <householdId>Sonos_SNBSD7YPBwpgYAw5W6b8Gf4TGS_211454cc</householdId>
            </loginToken>
        </credentials>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <reportAccountAction
            xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <type>addAccount</type>
        </reportAccountAction>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

And we dutifully reply:
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Body>
        <reportAccountActionResponse
            xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <reportAccountActionResult></reportAccountActionResult>
        </reportAccountActionResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Again, this is from Linux UPnP/1.0 Sonos/79.1-54060
getMetadata
This is where it goes wrong. We receive the getMetadata call without the token and key inside loginToken:
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Header>
        <credentials
            xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
            <loginToken>
                <householdId>Sonos_SNBSD7YPBwpgYAw5W6b8Gf4TGS_211454cc</householdId>
            </loginToken>
        </credentials>
        <ns:context>
            <contentFiltering>
                <explicit>false</explicit>
            </contentFiltering>
            <ns:timeZone>+01:00</ns:timeZone>
        </ns:context>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:getMetadata
            xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <id>root</id>
            <index>0</index>
            <count>100</count>
        </ns:getMetadata>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

And so we respond:
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>Client.LoginUnauthorized</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Failed to authenticate, try Re-Authorising your account in the sonos app</faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

The interesting thing is this is coming from a different client:
"POST /ws/sonos HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "pdsw-app-passport-android/80.6.04 (Android 13; Pixel 4a; google; sunfish) (Sonos/Universal-Content-Service 1.1.678)"

If I use the Sonos web app we get the same call and response, this time with this user-agent:
"POST /ws/sonos HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0 (Sonos/Universal-Content-Service 1.1.678)"

So I suppose I shouldn't be surprised - how would the other clients get the token to use? But I didn't read anything in the docs about how to handle this.

Following discussion with Sonos developer support, it turns out that the token and key arguments to loginToken are only passed in the first post-authorization call (in this case, to reportAccountAction).
Subsequently, the token only is passed in the Authorization HTTP header:
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzZXJ2aWNlVG9rZW4iOiJleUoxYzJWeWJtRnRaU0k2SW5SbGMzUkFaV3h6ZEdWdWMyOW1kSGRoY21VdVkyOXRJaXdpY0dGemMzZHZjbVFpT2lKWFNYUjJORVp6VlhWS1dFSjFZMlUyV0RGdk1pSjkiLCJpYXQiOjE3Mjc4ODI5MDYsImV4cCI6MTcyNzg4NjUwNn0.bb1pak6D3aoFeT4DEB-75w-hA-UHoE8K_nlyREc5ZU8

This means your SMAPI server must associate the token with the other information you require to successfully perform any authentication on your backend service.
